# when disable javascript , page can not postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I get a structure like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt"/>
<input runat="server" id="btn" onserverclick="btn_Click" type="image" src="demo.png"/>
```

When I input something in the textbox and hit Enter, the method btn_Click can be called. but when disabled javascript, it can not postback and the btn_Click method can not be called.

What's wrong with this?

Any help, thanks.

Comment: ASP.Net WebForms relies on Javascript.

Comment: Is there some methods to over this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the ASP.NET server side controls use JavaScript to post a `form` tag that surrounds the entire page content (look for the `<form runat="server">` tag in your source files, or for `<form name="aspnetForm">` in the HTML source in your browser).

Really, this behavior is so tightly engrained in WebForms, the use of 1 `form` tag for the entire page, and hidden inputs for the ViewState, event target, command argument, etc.

If you need functionality without JavaScript, you'll need a back to basics approach of simply relying on the HTTP protocol, by using just `GET` and `POST` requests with your own `form` tags (which can't be nested), and regular `a` tags.

Honestly, if you need functionality without JavaScript, it would probably be easier to switch over to [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).